# How do I reset the slider to slide 1 onLeave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using the latest version (2.1.8) of fullPage.js in order to create a dashboard, which automatically slides vertically and horizontally by updating the window.location.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bestify/tqza8d38/).

The issue I'm facing is that when we come back around to section 2, the slider is still on the final slide position and has to slide back to slide 1, before progressing forward through the slides.

I've tried following the instructions of [Issue #129](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/129) ,which looks to have worked for someone using version 1.7.2:

- Make scrollSlider function public
- Change the name of the calls to the function
- Apply onLeave event code:

  ```
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
      //getting the section by the index
      var section = $('.section').eq((index - 1));

      //if the section we are leaving has slides...
      if (section.find('.slides').length) {

          //moving to slide 0
          $.fn.fullpage.scrollSlider(section, 0);
      }
  }
  ```

However, this has no affect on the behaviour.

Is anybody able to suggest a method to ensure the slider is always put back to the default slide when moving to the next section using the latest version of fullPage.js?

All the best,

AshBestos

Comment: Now you can get a [fullpage.js extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/) to do so. This way  you can keep udpating fullpage.js without having to worry about possible bugs in your code or compatibility issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solved with a copy from function scrollSlider().

Named it function scrollDefault() and set this function public.

In my jquery.fullPage.custom.js

```
$.fn.fullpage.scrollDefault = function(section, slide){
  if(typeof slide != 'undefined'){
    var slides = section.find('.slides');
    var destiny =  slides.find('[data-anchor="'+slide+'"]');

    if(!destiny.length){
      destiny = slides.find('.slide').eq(slide);
    }

    if(destiny.length){
      landscapeScroll(slides, destiny);
    }
  }
};
```

The setTimeout is a quick & dirty solution to hide the scroll animation. So when you click on another section and go back you see the first slide.

In my $(document).ready(function() {

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var section = $('.section').eq((index - 1));
    if (section.find('.slides').length) {
      $.fn.fullpage.scrollDefault(section, 0);
    }
  }, 500);
}
```